# Meteor Accounts Remove Drop Down

Tags: meteor, user-accounts

By default, when I try to use `{{> loginButtons}}` to add any sign in functionality, the login fields are in wrapped within a sign in drop down. How do I remove this?

I just want the email and password field provided (create account, password reset, inclusive) by meteor without the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, it is not a trivial task to customize the default login buttons appearance.

What you can do instead is using a third party package that provides the accounts-ui you're looking for, try searching http://atmospherejs.com/ with the "accounts" keyword.

Probably even better is providing your own accounts-ui templates and only using Meteor accounts API to perform actual logging logic.

Here is my own login form template to get you started :

```
<template name="loginForm">
  <form class="login-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usernameOrEmail"
          placeholder="username or email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"
          placeholder="password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"
        data-loading-text="Logging in...">
      <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-check"></i> Login
    </button>
  </form>
</template>

Template.loginForm.events({
  "submit":function(event,template){
    event.preventDefault();
    var submitButton=template.$("button[type='submit']");
    submitButton.button("loading");
    //
    var usernameOrEmail=template.$("[name='usernameOrEmail']").val();
    var password=template.$("[name='password']").val();
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(usernameOrEmail,password,function(error){
      submitButton.button("reset");
      //
      if(error){
        console.log(error);
        return;
      }
      //
      template.find("form").reset();
    });
  }
});
```

Define a form template including only the fields you want, then in the submit event handler just call Meteor accounts API functions.

Advanced functionalities (resetting password, account creation, etc...) is quite straightforward if you follow the API docs : http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension to replace their template with your one. See here:

http://www.chaosstuff.com/2015/01/meteor-accounts-with-custom-login-form.html